# Segmentation fault in c using static array memory allocation.

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
        #include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
void f(char a[], int n, int k, int l);

int main(){
    int n; 
    int k; 
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    char number[100000];
    scanf("%s",number);
    int l= 0;
    if( n%2 == 0) f(number,n,k,l);
    else {l = 1;f(number,n,k,l);}
    return 0;
}
void f(char a[], int n, int k, int l) {
    int c = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i <= n/2; i++) {
        if( a[n/2 - 1 - i] > a[n/2 + l + i]) {a[n/2 + l + i] = a[n/2 - 1 - i];c++;}
        if( a[n/2 - 1 - i] < a[n/2 + l + i]) {a[n/2 - 1 - i] = a[n/2 + l + i]; c++;}
        if( c > k) {printf("-1"); break;}
    }
    if( c <= k) {
        int i = 0;
    while( c != k || c != (k-1)) {
        if( a[i] != 57) { a[i] = 57; a[n-1-i] = 57; c+=2;} 
        i++;
    }
        if(c == k-1 && n%2 == 1) a[n/2] = 57;
        printf("%s", a);
    }
    return;
}
```

I am trying to make a string of length n palindrome by changing k characters and make the digit as large as possible.
for ex.
input : 4 1
        3943
output : 3993
input : 6 3
        092282
output : 992299
Please guide me over segmentation fault and what is causing it.
Thanks a lot:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditional used in

```
while( c != k || c != (k-1)) {
```

is wrong. It will always be true. Due to that error, `i` keeps increasing and you end up accessing `a` out of bounds.

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`.

```
while( c != k && c != (k-1)) {
             ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you @R Sahu.
but that did not completely worked.
I am still getting segmentation fault in some testcases.